# Drive an older VFD tube via an Arduino et. al

Tags: arduino, i2c, vacuum-tube

[image]I have a beautiful old itron DP95A4 tube that I would like to use as a small display to visualize some data.
I suppose I'd need a driver and some sort of multiplexer, preferably used with an Arduino or similar.

Could anyone push me in a generel direction or did someone actually do something similar here?

Edit: Added picture as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Add a photo in to prompt someone's memory.

Comment: If you do a Google search on “vacuum fluorescent display arduino” you’ll find several successful hacks. A VFD is not the same as a “nixie” tube although both are encased in a glass bulb.

Comment: Hello. Well I could only find projects where single large VFD tubes or modern versions have been used, not the kind I am looking at. Thanks.